# Can I sell a calendar made from images of TV casts I found online?

Tags: legal, copyright

I want to make a monthly calendar and the images I want to use are cast members of CW show *One Tree Hill*.
Can I use cast images I find online and put a quote on them and sell the calendar?
Is that allowed?

Comment: vtc b/c This question is about copyright and ripping images from the internet, not photography.

Comment: Can I come over to your house and steal your television and stereo and then sell it on craigslist

Answer (score 4):

No. You would be creating and selling unlicensed merchandise; i.e., black market merch.; i.e. counterfeit goods.

- ['I almost got sued for knitting a Firefly hat': The legal risks of pop-culture fan art](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2044685/i-almost-got-sued-for-knitting-a-firefly-hat-the-legal-risks-of-pop-culture-fan-art.html), (pcworld.com): Fox issued a cease-and-desist letter (C&D) against an Etsy seller listing a one-off knit hat inspired by a character on the TV show *Firefly*. The Etsy seller removed the listing, choosing to comply with the C&D rather than engage in an expensive legal fight that likely would never have made it to court (intellectual property suits rarely are tried in court; there is strong incentive by corporate IP holders to *not* have their claims brought before a judge. Instead, they are usually settled out of court by the spectre of punishing legal costs. Corporate lawyers are just a business expense, but defense costs for people like Etsy sellers are usually personally crippling).

From [Copyrights and licensing for clothing lines](https://www.howtostartaclothingcompany.com/copyrights-licensing-for-clothing-lines/) (howtostartaclothingcompany.com),

> Depending on what you are trying to license, prepare to do alot of homework trying to track down who owns the rights to what you want to use. Let’s say you want to license a well known character from a popular movie. First, you’ll have to find out who owns the rights to this character. It could be the film company itself, or perhaps a company that licensed its use for films. [...]
>
> If you’re looking to license other types of properties such as characters or products, check out Licensing.org. [...]
>
> **No matter what you’re trying to license, you’ll most likely have to submit a proposal for review.** A proposal generally consists of your reasons for licensing this property, what products you intend to create with the license, and how you will market them.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you are not allowed to do that. Do you think The CW Network have no problem with anyone and everyone profiting from *their* intellectual property?

Just because you find an image online doesn't make it free. And there isn't a loophole just by mentioning where it's from.